# What am I doing wrong in my Kotlin Spring Boot Get API call with snakecase params leading to null parameters?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, binding

Why didn't the Get API call with params in snakecase is not working in Kotlin Spring boot

I have an API

```
@GetMapping("test1")
    fun getVersions(
        @RequestParam(value = "param_one", required = true) paramOne: Int,
        @RequestParam(value = "param_two", required = true) paramTwo: Int,
    ): ResponseEntity<String> {
        var output = "paramOne: $paramOne and paramTwo: #paramTwo"
        return ResponseEntity(output, HttpStatus.OK)
    }
```

when I hit this api with [localhost:8282/test1?param_one=1&param_two=2](https://stackoverflow.com) it worked.
output :`paramOne: 1 and paramTwo: 2`

so, I have removed all the @RequestParam and created a data class in kotlin

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy::class)
data class InputData(
   val paramOne: Int?,
   val paramTwo: Int?
)
```

and changed the code

```
@GetMapping("test1")
    fun getVersions(inputData: InputData): ResponseEntity<String> {
        var output = "paramOne: $paramOne and paramTwo: #paramTwo"
        return ResponseEntity(output, HttpStatus.OK)
    }
```

and tried with the same link [localhost:8282/test1?param_one=1&param_two=2](https://stackoverflow.com)  and it is giving me the below output,

```
paramOne: null and paramTwo: null
```

this is coming because the I have taken the argument name in snakecase. but actually I want this should be work. Can any one faced the similar issue please help me here.